# Can't find device when trying to install Lubuntu to HP Pavilion a1130n

Tags: boot, system-installation, lubuntu, hp

I'm trying to repurpose my ***old*** computer tower into a temporary/makeshift torrenting server. I love Ubuntu so I was going to try to replace Windows XP with Lubuntu. I've written the iso to a micro SD card and put into a USB adapter but when I boot, one, I don't know which menu to go to and, two, I can't find the device listed (recognisably) under any of them. I've looked in the `<Boot Menu>`, the `<Setup>` menu, and the `<System Recovery>` menu.

Again, it's an HP Pavilion a1130n running Windows XP and I'm trying to install Lubuntu.

Comment: What choices are shown in the BIOS boot menu?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Is the BIOS boot menu what shows up as `<Boot Menu>`?

Comment: Usually you enter the BIOS when booting the PC by pressing a key such as F4, Del, etc.  Then you get a choice of menus one of which usually lets you pick the boot device.  If that is not what you are referring to, my apologies.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'm sorry it's taken so long to get back to you; I've been volunteering with Team Internet and everything's been crazy the past week.

So I went into the BIOS, changed the boot priority from the hard drive to my USB, rebooted it, it took longer than normal, then I went to the "pick OS" screen and there were only two; Windows XP and Windows XP Recovery Edition. I installed Lubuntu using mkusb.